# Stop Onclick Execution when middle click is pressed - javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

This is something like my code:

```
<li class="dropdown" id="dropdown1"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li id="li-1"><a href="#" onclick="Alert("li-1")">List1</a></li>
       <li id="li-2"><a href="#" onclick="Alert("li-2")">List</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

but when middle click is pressed I want to stop execution of my onclick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this disables the onclick whenever the middle button is clicked

```js
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 2) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("middle button");
    $('a').prop("onclick", null); // disable onclick
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown" id="dropdown1"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="li-1"><a href="#" onclick='alert("li-1")'>List1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li-2"><a href="#" onclick='alert("li-2")'>List</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.button` can have a value of 0,1,2 representing left, middle, and right mouse button respectively. Knowing that, you can take advantage of [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to get the job done.

`(event.button !=1 ) && !alert('li-1')` Is basically the same as

```
if(event.button != 1){
 return !alert('li-i') // true (just to make sure the event it sent)
return false;
```

The first `li` in the snippet will `alert()` if it wasn't clicked by the middle mouse button, the second `li` will `alert()` if it wasn't clicked by the left mouse button.

```html
<li class="dropdown" id="dropdown1"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="li-1"><a href="#" onclick="(event.button!=1 ) && !alert('li-1')">List1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li-2"><a href="#" onclick="(event.button!= 0 ) && !alert('li-2')">List2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```